# How much static electricity can balloons generate?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, physics, electricity

The question '[Could a city be built out of Balloons?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108896/could-a-city-be-built-out-of-balloons)' has [an answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/108897/23519) mentioning using the static charge generated by the city as a power source.

Could a city built out of balloons generate enough power through static electricity to provide its own power?

[image]
This is a picture of a person cluster ballooning.
How much static electricity may this cluster it generate?
[image]
City made from a cluster of balloons.

Comment: Balloons (and everything else) do not geneate static electricity.  Hence the word "static."  The charge must be generated by something else (like the act of rubbing the balloon on your hair, the motion of your arms is the generator and the dispartiy of surface types a necessary condition).  Therefore, to forstall everyone who's voting to reopen the question (it is unclear in its present form because you can't "generate" static electricity, it's a consequence of something else), the answer is "no."

Comment: The question is rather moot anyway as you've not specified how much "power" a city needs. Cities did just fine before electricity, who needs heating when you're in an equatorial region and all the food can be eaten raw?