# Would there be any ways to theoretically have powered flight before the invention of an engine?

Tags: engineering, flight, aircraft

Would there be any ways to theoretically have powered flight before the invention of an engine?

I am trying to design some way to power a plane before the invention of the engine. I need the plane to be fast enough that it can keep itself aloft, but I do not have access to engines (at least, none which are efficient or light enough for use on a plane). Speed isn’t as necessary, but flight time is fairly important. The plane can be a lumbering beast as long as it can get where it’s going.

I have an artificer who gets information on future technologies from a patron, and could eventually build an engine for planes, but it will take quite some time to industrialize and I need something that can be made now (or at least, made decently quickly) with as few resources as possible.

The solution can be magic based (DnD 5e). To supplement any possible magic I have access to a material called Damestear, which is a magical battery mixed with a scroll, allowing anyone to use magic as long as they know how to activate the spell infused to the Damestear. If it is a magical solution then the lower the spell slot level required the better, as for every spell level the time to infuse the magic increases exponentially, and the number of people capable of infusing it lowers significantly.

Possible solutions don’t need to be rock solid, this is a fantasy setting, so numbers can be fudged a bit to work even if it wouldn’t in real life. My artificer currently has access to basic machine tools, and money/manpower are no limit. I am honestly not sure if there is a solution to this problem, but any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The solution can be magic based. Haven't you already answered your own question?

Comment: @L.Dutch I do not know what magic could be used to propel a plane through the air. I do not know all the ins and outs of 5e magic, much less magic usable by humans (magic abilities that aren't unique to a specific creature).

Comment: Also, I am hoping for a better answer than "it's magic, who cares", because that is frankly boring and uninspired.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. What parts would you say are "distracting"? As for the contraint, the question itself is the constraint. I am asking specifically about powered, heavier than air planes. That doesn't involve flying creatures. If I wanted to use flying creatures then the question wouldn't be about planes, it would be about how to best strap a 200 pound bomb to a pegasus.

Comment: "Powered" implies the presence of an engine, because that's what an engine *is*, a device that provides power. Whether that's a diesel engine or some kind of steam contraption or raw magic energy is up to you.

Comment: @TheEmperorProtects whether a science or magic based answer will have to depend on you drawing the line where on the scale of low fantasy like Game of Thrones (minus dragons), or high fantasy like Witcher or teehee fantasy like World of WarCraft with steampunk gnomes? Saying "its magic who cares is frankly boring" doesn't help us pin down what level of hard magic or hard science you want. Also, D&D setting can be very broad. When I picture D&D I personally think along the lines of Early to High Middle Ages. However, my current DM pictures Renaissance~Victorian era.

Comment: Define "an engine" // seeing as you mention D&D to me the magically animated skeleton of a hamster running eternally on a sealed wheel that powers your egg whisker is an engine, it may be powered by magic but it's still an engine, & as @Cadence points out "powered" in this context literally means that it has an engine making the question a kind of oxymoron, if it has an engine it's powered, if it doesn't it isn't, which means you de facto can't have powered flight without an engine.

Comment: [Sailplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(sailplane)) (also called gliders) have no engines and can stay aloft for quite a long time. In real history, [Otto Lilienthal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Lilienthal) designed and flew sailplanes in the 1890s.

Comment: @L.Dutch That magic can be used, and that the ruleset by which magic works is based on D&D 5e is very specific.  It cannot simply be handwaved... there are very specific rules as to what is and is not possible, and what it will cost to implement.

Comment: I'd propose a sailing airship, there's a topic about it, ref https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108896/could-a-city-be-built-out-of-balloons

Comment: How quickly can your artificer start manufacturing some really big rubber bands?

Comment: The question is not clear on whether you want your vehicle to be *aerostatic* (like a balloon) using wind-magic for directional power, or *aerodynamic* (wings-make-lift) using wind-magic to pass airflow over the wings.

Comment: There is a fanfiction of Gate: Thus the SDF fought there that mentioned how they use magic to force air through a double wing and creating thrust and lift for an iseikai-built aircraft

Comment: Could you provide a link to the explanation of magic? As Monty Wild mentioned, DnD magic is very specific so we need to know about these specifics to come up with satisfactory answers.

Comment: If there's no limit on manpower, then one of these designs ought to suit nicely :) -- https://hushkit.net/2021/08/23/top-ten-human-powered-aircraft/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Pulsejet.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsejet)**

With no fiddly pistons, crank-shafts, big ends issues, this might be a good bet:

[image: Pulsejet cycle.]

<sup>Tosaka via Wikipedia, 2022, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)</sup>

With few (or no) moving parts, this is about the most primitive sort of propulsion you'll get, just feed it something volatile like gasoline, terpene or alcohol and it'll produce resonant pulses of propulsive force. It'll require a small battery, coil and oscillating contacts to make an ignition spark - things for your adventurers to collect.

Beware: It's not exactly stealth. It sounds more like a giant angry wasp.

Comment: Is this really the answer ? It looks like a jet engine to me !

Comment: @Goodies It is a jet engine - it just doesn't use turbines.

Comment: @Goodies It fits the question's requirements - and it's easy to make.

Comment: @Goodies this is a type of pulse jet.  This is the type of propulsion used on German "buzz bombs" in WWII: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argus_As_014

Comment: I just wondered.. "before the engine" is in the title and this thing does require fuel and it was invented in 1917, after the Diesel engine. But this answer has been approved, so it may be what the opener is looking for ?

Comment: "I have an artificer who gets information on future technologies from a patron, and could eventually build an engine for planes" - but needs it right now, needing something simple to make. Then there was the discussion in the comments, now deleted which indicated that they wanted an engine. Then there's the magic battery to fit into the puzzle - I did. Yep, it's to the OP's specs. @Goodies

Comment: @ARogueAnt dream on.. this thing would never fit the weight of an aircraft.. you can't do a jet plane without engine development. I had a science teacher in school who made one of these as a hobby, the thing made a lot of noise, it was quite bulky, and if I remember correctly, propulsion forces were disappointing. I wonder if it could work.

Comment: Well I beg to differ, my magic pulsejet would work just fine, just needs a little pixie-dust in the fuel. Definitely not stealth though (unless they were stealth-pixies). @Goodies

Comment: Ow with magic, you can make it out of chicken wire, weight problem will be gone. And indeed the stealth capability of pulsejets is quite limited. You can hear this thing coming in from miles away. Your pixie dust fuel better be quick ! (lol)

Answer (score 7):

**No magic required**

It is entirely possible for humans to power their own flight, it'll just take some ingenuity, the right materials, and a good pair of legs, such as is the case of the [Daedalus human-powered flight project](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/hpa/SG_HPAG_daedalus.pdf), which had a flight time of basically four hours and covered seventy four miles(119.1km). You'll just have to exclude human legs from your definition of an 'engine' and then you'll have what you seek.

Comment: Slight edit to the answer to clarify that it's Daedalus-the-human-powered-flight-project, not Daedalus-the-mythical-character

Answer (score 5):

Of course, wind magic is the answer - summon (preferrably steady) strong winds in the desired direction, to "power" your [plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(sailplane)). Though it might be easier (if all you need is to transport one person) to use just [a piece of cloth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragliding) (suitably crafted, of course):

[image: Paraglilding]

But if you do not insist on heavier than air aircraft, then a (hot air, hydrogen or magic-lift) balloon is the answer - way easier to get it right in a low tech environment, *better* steerable if you can control the wind, can transport more weight...

Comment: Better proposals, +1 for the balloon, of course. Modern gliders have no engine, but keep in mind a glider parachute won't bring you far in a controlled way. Many modern materials were used for these gliders. A wind test was available, simulator-optimized shape design, special paints allow a good air resistance.. weight of the cables.. There's a lot of hi-tech needed !

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want magic, basically strap a bicycle like implement on top of an hot air/hydrogen/helium balloon. Connect the pedals to propellers and you get a quiet aircraft. It would move slowly and winds could blow faster than you can pedal but it is still an aircraft with no engine at all. Maybe you could use imps to pedal, better power to weight ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Rocketry. The Chinese implemented this technology centuries before the invention of engines.

Comment: This is a great answer IMO. Historically this is a possibility, and it's simple and doesn't require advanced theories or calculations.

Comment: Legendarily, Wan Hu got airborne about 500 years ago via rocket power. Those sent downrange claimed that they couldn't find the body or any wreckage. My personal theory is that they found it easier to claim nothing was found than to clean up the mess.  With some more modern information, a rocket launched glider would (possibly with some smalker rockets if additionallift is needed later) would be a great solution to the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a fantasy setting, then we can find many examples from movies and tales.

1. Magic carpet as in Aladdin.
2. Genie as in Thief of Baghdad.
3. Wings of Daedalus.
4. Some kind of power as Throne of Queen of Sheba was brought from
   Yemen to Jerusalem in the twinkling of an eye.